# I am trying to migrate from hibernate to JPA and came across the Restrictions.ilike for hibernate Critereons. How do I convert this to JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, migration, restriction

Is there anyway to convert the code below to JPA without using hibernate? I have been doing some looking around and came up with nothing. Thanks in advance!

deCrit.add(Restrictions.ilike(fieldName,
fieldValue, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));

Answer (score 0):

so you will have a jpa criteria object on which you can invoke the where method passing an array of predicates. something similar to

```
    String fieldValue = "search terms";
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<AType> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(AType.class);
    Root<AType> somePath = criteriaQuery.from(AType.class);
    criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.upper(somePath.get("fieldName")),
            "%" + fieldValue.toUpperCase() + "%"));
    List<AType> result = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```